# expandable listview is not showing any data at initial phase. but shows after clicking the button

Tags: android

I am trying to display the item in expandable listview after calculating the distance from the google direction api but it gives empty list but when clicked in the search button it is displayed. Please suggest me to get rid out of this problem

```
public List<SqliteServiceCenterListData> getAllInfo(String countryName, final String userLocationLatitude, final String userLocationLongitude) {
            final List<SqliteServiceCenterListData> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM service_center_info WHERE  country_name=?";
            final Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[]{countryName.trim()});
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
                final SqliteServiceCenterListData sqliteServiceCenterListData = new SqliteServiceCenterListData();
                sqliteServiceCenterListData.setCountryId(cursor.getString(1));
                sqliteServiceCenterListData.setZoneId(cursor.getString(2));
                sqliteServiceCenterListData.setCityId(cursor.getString(3));
                sqliteServiceCenterListData.setServiceCenterId(cursor.getString(4));
                sqliteServiceCenterListData.setCountryName(cursor.getString(5));
                sqliteServiceCenterListData.setZoneName(cursor.getString(6));
                sqliteServiceCenterListData.setCityName(cursor.getString(7));
                sqliteServiceCenterListData.setServiceCenterName(cursor.getString(8));
                sqliteServiceCenterListData.setOpeningTime(cursor.getString(9));
                sqliteServiceCenterListData.setClosingTime(cursor.getString(10));
                sqliteServiceCenterListData.setLocation(cursor.getString(11));
                sqliteServiceCenterListData.setContact(cursor.getString(12));
                sqliteServiceCenterListData.setContactPerson(cursor.getString(13));
                sqliteServiceCenterListData.setLatitude(cursor.getString(14));
                sqliteServiceCenterListData.setLongitude(cursor.getString(15));
                if (new ConnectionManager(context).isConnectionToInternet()) {
                    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                        @Override
                        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                            new GetDistanceFromServer(context, String.valueOf(userLocationLatitude), String.valueOf(userLocationLongitude), sqliteServiceCenterListData.getLatitude(), sqliteServiceCenterListData.getLongitude()).getDistanceFromServer(new DistanceInfoHolder() {
                                @Override
                                public void setDistance(String distance) {
                                    Log.e("Distance", distance);
                                    sqliteServiceCenterListData.setDistances(distance);
                                    dataList.add(sqliteServiceCenterListData);
                                }
                            });
                            return null;
                        }
                    }.execute();
                } else {
                    dataList.add(sqliteServiceCenterListData);
                }
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            cursor.close();
            db.close();
            return dataList;
        }
```

Comment: And what is this???? Can't able to see your code its mess until and unless it is not formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in the getGroupView of the adapter

```
((ExpandableListView) parent).expandGroup(groupPosition);
```